how can I set background image in cavas from Fabric?
I would like to upload an image and set it as the html5 canvas background but I am also using FabricJS and my application is built using NUXT.
I am getting the error:
Uncaught TypeError: canvas.setBackgroundImage is not a function
at imageElement.onload
and here is my code:
const uploadBackgroundImage = (event: Event) => {
  const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  if (input.files && input.files[0] && canvas) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) {
      const imgSrc = e.target?.result as string;

      console.log("Base64 image string:", imgSrc);  // Log the base64 string

      const imageElement = new Image();
      imageElement.src = imgSrc;

      // When the image is loaded, set it as the Fabric.js background image
      imageElement.onload = () => {
        const fabricImage = new fabric.Image(imageElement);

        // Scale the image to fit the canvas
        fabricImage.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
        fabricImage.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);

        // Set the background image and re-render the canvas
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(fabricImage, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
      };

      // Handle error if the image fails to load
      imageElement.onerror = () => {
        console.error('Failed to load base64 image.');
      };
    };

    // Here is the missing step: read the image as a Data URL (base64)
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);  // This will generate the base64 string
  }
};


The method setBackgroundImage was removed in Fabric. 6.0.0 (breaking changes). You can achieve the same effect with the following:
fabricImage.selectable = false; // make it unselectable
fabricImage.evented = false;
canvas.add(fabricImage);
canvas.sendToBack(fabricImage); // move to back layer
canvas.requestRenderAll();

